# Denoting set of complex numbers with identical magnitude

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to calculate the $log$ of all numbers with a magnitude of 1, how can I denote that? Ideally, in wolfram alpha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\log e^{ic}$ where $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How do I do this in wolfram alpha?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28e^ix%29+for+all+real+x